# Callling class instance method doesn't print anything

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instantiation

```
class mainClass:

    def greeting():
        mydata = input('How are you?')
        print(mydata)

m1 = mainClass()
m1.greeting()
```

Question:
Why does `m1.greeting()` not work?

Rephrased: Why does `m1.greeting()` not `print(my data)`?

Comment: You forgot to use the `self` argument :) `def greeting(self):`

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not work". What was the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to either pass `self`

```
def greeting(self):
    mydata = input('How are you?')
    print(mydata)
```

or declare `greeting` a `classmethod`

```
@classmethod
def greeting():
    mydata = input('How are you?')
    print(mydata)
```

Unless there is more to follow, there isn't really a reason to introduce OOP here, `greeting` might as well just be a free function.

Comment: Thanks, then why does this not work?```class C:
    def g(self):
        return 'hello world'

instantiateClassC = C()
instantiateClassC.g()```

Answer (score 0):

You may declare a `self` parameter when creating function, or using `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` with `cls` parameter. Check them below. You may read the differences [here](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/).

**Declaring `self` parameter when creating function**:

```
class mainClass:
    def greeting(self):
        mydata = input('How are you? ')
        print(mydata)
```

**Using `@staticmethod` which does not require passing any parameter**:

```
@staticmethod
def greeting():
    mydata = input('How are you? ')
    print(mydata)
```

**Using `@classmethod` which DOES require passing `cls` parameter**:

```
@classmethod
def greeting(cls):
    mydata = input('How are you? ')
    print(mydata)
```

These are the three ways to solve your problem.

I also recommend obeying [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) rules regarding naming Classes:

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

Which means you should (in my opinion it's better) to rename your class to `MainClass`.

Should you have any questions or problems, drop comment below so that I can assist you if I can.